# How to pass job level environment variable between jobs - Github Actions

Tags: github, environment-variables, github-actions

I wish to read `var1=good` inside  mainjob2, however, it does not print.

```
name: Main Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  mainjob1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Set Variable
        run: |
          echo "var1=good" >> $env:GITHUB_ENV

  mainjob2:
    needs: mainjob1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:

      - name: Access Variable
        run: |
          echo "var1=${{ env.var1 }}"
```

I need help with Access Variable step.

I tried the below but none of them worked.

```
          echo "var1=${{ needs.mainjob1.env.var1 }}"
          echo "var1=${{ needs.mainjob1.output.env.var1 }}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```yaml
name: Main Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  mainjob1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      var1: ${{ steps.set_var.outputs.var1 }}
    steps:
      - name: Set Variable
        id: set_var
        run: |
          echo "var1=good" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  mainjob2:
    needs: mainjob1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:

      - name: Access Variable
        run: |
          echo "var1=${{ needs.mainjob1.outputs.var1 }}"
```

Comment: your answer does not works

Comment: @Ashar oops sorry i forgot to declare the `outputs` section! See updated answer.

Comment: works, I accept the answer but my requirement was different so posting new here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76320355/how-to-pass-dynamically-populated-job-level-environment-variables-between-jobs