# How to pass dynamically populated job level environment variables between jobs - Github Actions

Tags: github, scope, environment-variables, github-actions, dynamic-variables

It is known how to pass a known variable from one job to another as shown in the answer here:

[How to pass job level environment variable between jobs - Github Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76319572/how-to-pass-job-level-environment-variable-between-jobs-github-actions)

But, my case is different. In my case the variable `echo "var1=good" >> $env:GITHUB_ENV` is not known. Instead, a list of `key=value` is constructed dynamically from a variable and appended to `GITHUB_OUTPUT` and `GITHUB_ENV` as shown in the example below:

```
name: Main Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  mainjob1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      ---> don't know how to list dynamic key-values from the ForEach loop
    steps:

#      - name: Set Single known Variable
#        id: split
#        run: |
#          echo "var1=good" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Set Dynamic Variable list using ForEach loop
        run: |
          "${{ needs.READ_VARS_FROM_XML.outputs.key_value_x }}" -split '[\r\n]+' | ForEach-Object {
              $trimvalue = $_.Trim()
              echo "$trimvalue" >>  $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT
              echo "$trimvalue" >>  $env:GITHUB_ENV
            }
        id: split

      - name: Print sample single key-value from the dynamic variable list
        run: |
          echo "PORT NUMBER: ${{ env.port }} or ${{ steps.split.output.port }}" 

  mainjob2:
    needs: mainjob1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:

      - name: Access Variable
        run: |
          ---> Dont know how to print dynamic populated key-values here
#          echo "var1=${{ needs.mainjob1.outputs.var1 }}"
```

How do I access this dynamic key=value list in another job as the `outputs:` at job level is not known?

Comment: Put such values it in a file, upload it as an artifact, download it in the next job, and use it there.

Comment: See [Storing workflow data as artifacts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts).